# Add a column and populate it with the queried values from another column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column having dates in varchar format, I want to convert it, to `date` format, which I did through below query:

```
select to_date(EVENT_DT, 'YYYYMMDD') from demographic;
```

Now, I want to create a new column and populate the column with the values that I got from above query. I am not able to do it with `alter table`.

Any solutions?

Comment: you could alter the table and add the new column and then update the column with the correct information.  Or, you could create a new table with the column data that you want.  Either way, you'd be recreating the micro-partitions underneath, so I'd just go with a CTAS and drop the original table afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it works as @Mike Walton said

```
Alter table demographic add Converted_date date;       
 ----ms sql server
Update demographic set Converted_date = convert(date, EVENT_DT , 101);
 ---or using to_date
Update demographic set Converted_date = to_date(EVENT_DT, 'YYYYMMDD');
```